# Can someone help me make arrays from JSON with all the same keys?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here's the JSON I have

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "picture": "image-hero-paramour.jpg",
        "title": "Project Paramour",
        "subheading": "Project made for an art museum near Southwest London. Project Paramour is a statement of bold, modern architecture."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "picture": "image-hero-seraph.jpg",
        "title": "Seraph Station",
        "subheading": "The Seraph Station project challenged us to design a unique station that would transport people through time. The result is a fresh and futuristic model inspired by space stations."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "picture": "image-hero-federal.jpg",
        "title": "Federal II Tower",
        "subheading": "A sequel theme project for a tower originally built in the 1800s. We achieved this with a striking look of brutal minimalism with modern touches."
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "picture": "image-hero-trinity.jpg",
        "title": "Trinity Bank Tower",
        "subheading": "Trinity Bank challenged us to make a concept for a 84 story building located in the middle of a city with a high earthquake frequency. For this project we used curves to blend design and stability to meet our objectives."
    }
]
```

If I wanted to make an array like this:
`let titles = ["Project Paramour", "Seraph Station", "Federal II Tower", "Trinity Bank Tower"]`,
how could I do that?
And also make another 3 arrays for the other 3 JSON keys.

Thank you!!

Comment: Is your intention to generate the arrays for each key automatically?

Comment: I can either do it automatically or I can just make each array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map()

console.log(data.map(i=>i.title))

Comment: Wow, sure a simple solution which worked perfectly. The perfect code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function and pick the property you want to store in the new array like this

```js
const ids = array.map(object => object.id)
const titles = array.map(object => object.title)
const pictures = array.map(object => object.picture)
const subheadings = array.map(object => object.subheading)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to select a specific field from each object.

E.g. in this example `titles` is the list of all titles and `pictures` is the list of all pictures:

```js
const array = [{
    "id": 1,
    "picture": "image-hero-paramour.jpg",
    "title": "Project Paramour",
    "subheading": "Project made for an art museum near Southwest London. Project Paramour is a statement of bold, modern architecture."
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "picture": "image-hero-seraph.jpg",
    "title": "Seraph Station",
    "subheading": "The Seraph Station project challenged us to design a unique station that would transport people through time. The result is a fresh and futuristic model inspired by space stations."
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "picture": "image-hero-federal.jpg",
    "title": "Federal II Tower",
    "subheading": "A sequel theme project for a tower originally built in the 1800s. We achieved this with a striking look of brutal minimalism with modern touches."
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "picture": "image-hero-trinity.jpg",
    "title": "Trinity Bank Tower",
    "subheading": "Trinity Bank challenged us to make a concept for a 84 story building located in the middle of a city with a high earthquake frequency. For this project we used curves to blend design and stability to meet our objectives."
  }
]

const titles = array.map(item => item.title)
const pictures = array.map(item => item.picture)

console.log({
  titles,
  pictures
})
```